# Taskkill.exe: don't throw an error if the process is not running

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, tasks

I'm running a Visual Studio post build event that shuts down IIS if it's still running after compilation:

```
taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe
```

The following works perfectly if IIS is still running, but throws an error if it has already stopped:

```
Error 1 The process "w3wp.exe" not found. xxx\EXEC
```

Is there a way to tell taskkill to ignore the problem if it can't find a matching running process?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of running one command, would running a small batch file work instead?

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq w3wp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "w3wp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe
```

Answer (score 30):

The solution I found to this was to run

```
START /wait taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe
```

It returns a success from the START command, and any error thrown by TASKKILL is thrown in the new console window

Comment: and if you want to wait for tasks to be killed before continuing with the batch file. simply add: `START /wait taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe`

Comment: The wait is a very important detail. I will edit that into the original answer to avoid confusion. Thanks @jezternz !

Answer (score 22):

This works well too:

```
taskkill /IM "w3wp.exe" /F /FI "STATUS eq RUNNING"
```

Comment: I could not get this to work - my version of taskkill does not seem to recognise "STATUS eq RUNNING". However, "MEMUSAGE gt 2" does work.

Comment: I found that "STATUS eq UNKNOWN" was a better option for catching processes that may or may not be stuck (but either way, you don't want them)

Comment: "STATUS ne UNKNOWN" -> not equal unknown -> kill if it exists was working for me.

Answer (score 11):

Or, this will just return an info message if not found:

```
taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe /fi "memusage gt 2"
```

Info from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010702/746754)

Answer (score 5):

This is a **one line solution**.

It will run taskkill only if the process is really running otherwise it will just info that it is not running.

```
tasklist | find /i "w3wp.exe" && taskkill /im w3wp.exe /F || echo process "w3wp.exe" not running.
```

This is the output in case the process was running:

```
w3wp.exe           1960 Services                   0    112,260 K
SUCCESS: The process "w3wp.exe" with PID 1960 has been terminated.
```

This is the output in case not running:

```
process "w3wp.exe" not running.
```

Answer (score 5):

For a prebuild event in visual studio this worked for me:

```
taskkill /f /im scriptcode.exe 2>nul 1>nul
exit 0
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806444/swallowing-errors-in-pre-build-steps-in-visual-studio-2010

I had some problems with status = running checks, process existed but did not have status = running.  I was using that before.

Answer (score 1):

Forces the process to kill (if the process is running), and don't output any information.

The following command work fine.

`taskkill /f /im w3wp.exe /t /fi "status eq running">nul`

Comment: How will this kill w3wp.exe?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to *not* display the error, this works:

```
taskkill /im test.exe 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Append `|| exit 0`

**Details**

I cannot test the exact case given, but I found this works:

```
pskill w3wp.exe || exit 0
```

The '||' says run the second command if the first fails. A ';' should work as well.

Additionally to totally silence a command use something like:

```
rem totally silent
rem order matters. Redirect then join
some_cmd 1>nul: 2>>&1
```